# Node.js pattern matching logic

Tags: javascript, node.js, pattern-matching

I am new to node.js and I have a requirement where I need to read txt file where I need to match different patterns in it. So, lets say it has  A~B~C which should match with *!B!C. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier for us to answer your question if you show your existing code and tell us what exactly doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Performance issues aside, you can use regular expressions in javascript to do that kind of text pattern matching.  MDN has a pretty good overview:
[MDN Regular Expressions Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

If you're new to regexes or need to brush up, I also found this site to be extremely helpful.
http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Be aware that there are a few JavaScript-specific formatting issues to know about.  That site also covers those.

I have seen others recommend using a character buffer instead of a string object if performance becomes a constraint.  Good luck!

Comment: JS's RegExp performance is a LOT better than it was a couple years ago, especially V8...

Comment: BUt how to read file line by line and then how to compare? A small piece of Pseudo Code will really help ? Thanks for your responses !